# Xcode 6.3.1, Swift, iOS 8 Interface Builder - Uninstall button when landscape

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Is it possible to uninstall a button when the device is in landscape?

I would have thought I could uninstall a button in the same way I uninstall a constraint - yet I can't work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it in the interface builder:

1. Set Interface builder to landscape (wAny hCompact)
2. Select the button (View Controller > View > Button)
3. Attributes Inspector (scroll all the way to the bottom)
4. Uncheck 'Installed'

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
@IBOutlet weak var btn_MyButton: UIButton!

override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    switch UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation{
    case .LandscapeLeft:
        btn_MyButton.hidden = true
    case .LandscapeRight:
        btn_MyButton.hidden = true
    default:
        btn_MyButton.hidden = false
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code answer. I'm forcing myself to learn the interface builder on this project.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your button or hide it

```
btn.removeFromSuperview()
//or
btn.hidden = true
```

Comment: Thanks for offering a code suggestion. I'm trying to use the interface builder to solve this problem.